# condition for model anytime I refer to it yii

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have model Post and Article which is inherited by Post. Table tbl_post contains text records (title, text, type) where type may be:
1 - article (model Article)
2 - news (model News) 
etc.

I want model Article to return only records where type=1 (for example) whenever I refer to it.
How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `defaultScope`-function in the Article model:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
   return array
   (
      'condition' => 'type = 1' 
   );
}
```

That is the easiest way I can think of. You can then just do `Article::model()->findAll()` or something like that and it should only return articles.

Comment: yeah, it works in the Post model but not in the Article. I've no the remotest idea why. The method `defaultScope` in the Article model is not called.

Comment: If one is derived from the other, you need to make sure to override it again in the derived class. The defaultScope() is normally called for everything model-related that you do using the official functions (findX etc)

Comment: It works great. I just forgot to declare `static function model($className=__CLASS__)` in the Article model.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Blizzke/9707266 - small excerpt from my own active record class. I just derive everything from that instead. Never forget the model function again. The setDbCriteria call is not strictly necessary, but better safe than sorry. The resetScope is to make sure I don't end up with stray conditions.